# Join Strings in Query output

Tags: sql, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have this query that "i'd like to convert to MongoDB. Is it possible to do this without resorting to javascript?

```
SELECT FirstName, Lastname, FirstName + " " + LastName AS FullName FROM Users
```

Also, I am using the most recent version of MongoDB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only things that can "alter" the form of a returned document are [`.aggregate()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) and [`.mapReduce()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.mapReduce/). In this case, [`.aggregate()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) is the better form with [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) and the [`$concat`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/concat/) operator:

```js
db.users.aggregate([
   { "$project": {
       "FirstName": 1,
       "Lastname": 1,
       "FullName": { "$concat": [ "$FirstName", " ", "$Lastname" ] }
   }}
])
```